# Are 'fluff' setting related questions relevant?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I was about to ask for help coming up with a list of titles that fit in with the theme of the WH:40K universe (and with Rogue Trader in particular). Latin isn't my first language =)
In particular, I wanted a title for a character that had risen in the administrative/logistical ranks of a ministorium.

Other questions related to fluff, for example, could asking for background details on the Lovecraft Mythos.

Are questions like this on topic?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### If it's RPG-setting-specific and meets the other site guidelines for questions, they're fine.

A question about the Lovecraftian Mythos would be better off in the [Science Fiction & Fantasy SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/), but [questions about the 4e Points of Light setting](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdnd-4e%5D+%22points+of+light%22+is%3Aquestion) are on topic here.

The reason for this is that we can have an RPG in any setting--real-life 1920s New England, Middle-Earth, the world of Tron--and that means it'd be easy to have any question about *anything* be on topic. So we have to limit it to RPG-only settings, both to keep the site from ballooning like a foam dinosaur in the bathtub and because we aren't the experts equipped to answer most of those questions. (Some non-RPG-setting-specific questions are re-opened on a case-by-case basis, and the topic is, of course, open for discussion on meta. The less likely it is that another SE or forum could answer the question usefully, the more likely we are to take that question under our wing.)

The main problem with your question is not that it's a setting question, but that it's asking for an open-ended, speculative list of original ideas. If any answer could be added to indefinitely, and there's no clear way to tell if an answer is actually helpful, that just creates "noise" on the site.

Comment: You'd be better off asking for title ideas in a traditional RPG forum, or maybe in [the rpg.se chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat).

Comment: Good idea, thanks =)

Answer (score 4):

### Roleplaying Games Are Their Own Context

There are meta considerations in terms of setting-creation if you are going to set loose a bunch of PCs in it.  Assumptions and best-practices that are *instinctual* to a good GM.

As such, if it's a setting-question in terms of **running a game in it**, it should be answered by people with experience in running games in that setting, or playing in games set in that setting, i.e., players and GMs.

Having someone who has never played a roleplaying game in their life give a fluff answer that *does not work well in a roleplaying context* is not a good answer to a RPG fluff question.

Comment: If you want to propose that the site re-visits its policy on setting questions, you should make that a new meta post after [reviewing the previous discussion on the topic](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1604/4398).